# Reduce result of elasticsearch aggregation: array of objects to simple array of numbers

Tags: json, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

Having such an elasticsearch aggregation:

```
"users":{  
  "terms":{  
    "field":"user_id.keyword",
    "size":100
  },
  "aggs":{  
    "max_page_visited":{  
      "max":{  
        "field":"post.current_page"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

It returns 100 users and the max number page visited for every user:

```
"users": {
  "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
  "sum_other_doc_count": 4,
  "buckets": [
    {
      "key": "user_1",
      "doc_count": 1,
      "max_page_visited": {
        "value": 10
      }
    },
    {
      "key": "user_2",
      "doc_count": 1,
      "max_page_visited": {
        "value": 12
      }
    },
    {/* other 98 users */}
  ]
}
```

Is there an aggregation or bucket script to just return the `max_page_visited` values?

So the list of 100 numbers is expected to be returned: `[10, 12, /* other 98 values */]`

Comment: are you using any scripting language to use that elasticsearch json response?

Comment: @BeingSunny, yeap, as a last reason, I can handle this post-processing on the programming language side. But I'm looking for a elasticsearch-side solution

Comment: @LarryCinnabar never heard any aggregation to match with your requirement. Post processing could be the approach that you may take.

Comment: @bhoo-day ok then ;)